# Parallel processing through tcl script

Tags: multithreading, tcl

Need solution for parallel processing in tcl (windows).

I tried with thread, still not able to achieve desired output.

**To simplify My requirement I am giving a simple example as following.**
**Requirement:**
I want to run notepad.exe without effecting my current execution of flow. From main thread control should go to called thread, start notepad.exe and come back to main thread with out closing the notepad .

**Tried:(Tcl script)**

package require Thread

set a 10

proc test_thread {b} {

```
puts "in procedure $b"
set tid [thread::create] ;# Create a thread
return $tid
```

}

puts "main thread"

puts [thread::id]

set ttid [test_thread $a]

thread::send $ttid {exec c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe &}

puts "end"

**Getting Output:**
running notepad without showing any log.
when closing notepad application I am getting following output.

main thread

tid0000000000001214

in procedure 10

end

**Desired output:** 
main thread

tid0000000000001214

in procedure 10

---->> *control should go to thread and run notepad.exe with out effecting main thread flow.*
<<-------
end

So kindly help to solve this issue and if appart from thread concept any other is there let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a synchronous `thread::send`. It's the version that is most convenient for when you want to get a value back, but it does wait. You probably should be using the *asynchronous* version:

```
thread::send -async $ttid {exec c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe &}
#            ^^^^^^ This flag here is what you need to add
```

However it is curious that the `exec` call is behaving as you describe at all; the `&` *at the end* should make it effectively asynchronous anyway. Unless there's some sort of nasty interaction with how Windows is interpreting asynchronous subprocess creation in this case.

Comment: **You probably should be using the asynchronous version**

Comment: Thanks **You probably should be using the asynchronous version** may I know which version of tcl is for asynchronous. I tried with -async option but it does not allow to start the notepad application. I am using tcl 8.6. If you have any other approach to solve this issue please let me know.